# Как правильно указать лицензию в своем приложении?

Tags: android, авторские-права

Нужно ли добавлять в приложение перечень используемых библиотек и лицензии на их распространение ?

Как вы решаете подобные вопросы ?

Раскройте, пожалуйста, ответ для двух вариантов:

- инди разработчик (с наличием или отсутствием монетизации приложения);
- приложение, выполненное, к примеру, на фрилансе.

Comment: Прочитайте лицензии используемых библиотек. Там содержится исчерпывающая информация о том, что и как указывать в своей лицензии. Все зависит от лицензий конкретных библиотек

Comment: @metalurgus, понятно. Тогда я просто где-нибудь в приложении составляю список библиотек и под каждой пишу то, что требует от меня автор.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для тех, кому еще это нужно. Пример для пары библиотек `Google`.

Текст, который необходимо указать для них:

> **Apache License Version 2.0**
>
> - Android Support Library
>
> Copyright (c) Google Inc. All rights reserved.
>
> - Google Play Services
>
> Copyright (c) Google Inc. All rights reserved.

И так далее продолжаете перечень. После нужно указать текст ниже:

> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you
>   may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may
>   obtain a copy of the License at
>
> ```
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
> ```
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and limitations under the License.

Текст взят с официального сайта [`Apache`](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

Когда закончите с [`Apache`](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), и у Вас будут другие типы лицензий в приложении, то Вам нужно будет повторить принцип описания и для них.

> **Тип лицензии**
>
> Перечень
>
> То, что требуется указать при распространении.

// Прошу меня поправить, если я в чем-то ошибся. Как понял принцип, так его и описал в ответе. Надеюсь, что он пригодится многим))