# Лицензии библиотек в андроид-приложении

Tags: android, лицензирование

1. Лицензии каких библиотек должны быть описаны в приложении? Только сторонних библиотек с GitHub-а, или библиотек Google также? [В статье хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/274859/) написано только про библиотеки с GitHub-а:

> Часто при реализации мобильного приложения для Android c
>   использованием в нем различных сторонних библиотек требуется их
>   упомянуть в своем проекте, чтоб не нарушать права 3-х лиц и не попасть
>   в бан с вашим проектом в магазине приложений Google Play. В приложение
>   нам нужно поместить описание использованных библиотек и указать их
>   лицензию. Речь идет о библиотеках, которые находятся на GitHub.

Но при этом [в одном из ответов SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502704/189882) указаны также Android Support Library и Google Play Services... Нужно ли помещать лицензии для этих библиотек в приложение?

2. Каким образом нужно "упомянуть в своем проекте" эти библиотеки? Есть ли какие-либо обязательные требования, где именно должны располагаться описание библиотеки и текст лицензии на неё, как это должно выглядеть?
3. И где в правилах для разработчиков Google Play указано, что необходимо помещать в приложение текст лицензии, чтобы он был виден пользователю? Я искала в ["Соглашении Google Play о распространении программных продуктов"](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ru/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) 
   и в целом в ["Центре правил для разработчиков"](https://play.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none) (в том числе в разделе ["Выдача себя за другое лицо и интеллектуальная собственность"](https://play.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/about/ip-impersonation/ip/)), но не нашла нигде этого требования. Может, не обязательно указывать именно текст лицензии, а просто в описании приложения в Google Play можно указать ссылку на страницу Github? Была бы благодарна за ссылку на это требование, если таковое всё-таки существует.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Требований как таковых в Google Play вы не найдете. Причина проста: звучит примерно так, как если бы у вас требовали при поступлении на работу "не красть, не убивать и никого не бить" :) Это как бы само собой разумеется. Здесь предполагается, что при публикации автор обязуется придерживаться законодательство о копирайте (авторском праве).

Требования содержатся в тексте лицензии библиотеки и/или продукта, который вы используете в своем приложении. Например, типичная ссылка на лицензию которой оснащены большинство библиотек в github выглядит приблизительно так:

> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

Грубо говоря, обычно пишется, что условия использования приведены в тексте лицензии. Лезем в лицензию (в данном случае Apache 2.0). Отбросим юридические бла-бла обнаруживаем, что:

При распространении программного обеспечения необходимо приложить к ПО следующую информацию:

- содержание текста лицензии Apache;
- текст перечисляющий все библиотеки, лицензированные под лицензией Apache вместе с именами их создателей.

Если бы лицензия была бы [GPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) то требования там уже другие. В частности необходимо дистрибутировать еще и тексты исходного кода или письменного обязательства его предоставить (своего или чужого; способы зависят от версии лицензии)

Для лицензии [copyleft](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%82) - вообще ничего не требуется.

В общем, мессидж простой: внимательно читайте лицензии. Там все указано. Если нет лицензии - предполагается, что продукт использовать нельзя. В таком случае пишите письмо автору, пусть он напишет waiver или что-то типа такого (на практике все пишут *waiver* - отказ от прав)

**Update**

Про наказание за нарушение норма авторского права:

Уверяю вас, что если приложение будет иметь хотя бы 100 тыс. загрузок найдется [добрыйй самаритянин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5), который донесет кому надо и вашу аппу заблочат немедленно, а то и в суд подадут. Я лично уже имел "счастье" познакомиться с такими методами. Так что не советую. Проще написать пару-тройку методов/лейаутов и подстраховаться. Тем более что это фактически *copy-paste*

Comment: Вообще при поступлении на работу обычно требование "не красть" прописывается в договоре) в договоре о неразглашении коммерческой тайны" :)

Comment: коммерческая тайна понятие растяжимое, именно поэтому при поступлении на работу конкретно специфицируется что является коммерческой тайной. Например состав учредителей не может являться коммерческой тайной, равно как и баланс предприятия

Comment: Что будет если забить на это все и не делать этого? Создатель либы сам должен найти, кто ее украл и пожаловаться?

Comment: И, получается, текст лицензии нужно разместить где-нибудь в приложении, чтобы он был виден пользователю, но где - не важно?

Comment: Приблизительно так. Обычно принято в где-нибудь в *About* или *Settings*. Для примера, в Facebook это распологается в блоке *About->Licences*

Comment: @Kostya уверяю вас, что если приложение будет иметь хотя бы 100 тыс. загрузок найдется сердобольный самаритянин, который донесет кому надо и вашу аппу заблочат немедленно, а то и в суд подадут. Я лично уже имел "счастье" познакомиться с такими методами.

Comment: @Barmaley если приложение заблочили, то разблочить нереально уже? Ну например добавить лицензии уже как нашли, что их нет

Comment: Бывают разные ситуации. Бывают блочат и дают срок чтобы исправиться, бывает сразу "режут", бывает люди через знакомых в сервисной службе как то разблокируют... Бывает все что угодно. Но для простых смертных как мы с вами более-менее работает правило: в первый раз не блочат - предупреждают, со второго раза бьют сразу по башке, если не понимаешь вообще блокируют девелоперский аккаунт или даже вообще весь Google Id

Comment: @Barmaley, а если не секрет, чем закончилось Ваше знакомство с этими методами ("Я лично уже имел "счастье" познакомиться с такими методами")? просто любопытно))

Comment: Закончилось тем, что я мне выставили претензию за использование чужого товарного знака и заблокировали приложение на территории США/Канады. Я связывался с правообладателем, но они переслали меня к своему юристу. В итоге я просто зарегистрировал альтернативное торговую марку, они пытались ее оспорить, но не смогли. Сейчас готовлю новое приложение с другим пакетом и буду публиковать. Компания довольно известная - посмотрим что будет :)

Comment: @Barmaley, интересная история) Удачи Вам! :)